# Endless function calls in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to make endless function calls in javascript?

```
func1();
console.log('next');
func1();
console.log('next');
func1();

//endless - infinite loop
```

Without `SetInterval`, `SetTimeout` functions. Browser must to respond to user actions.

Comment: Can you explain that last statement? Because `setInterval` and `setTimeout` *allow* for a responsive browser.

Comment: What is the intended outcome? What is the context? Very broad question.

Comment: I can not use this functions in script. (SetInterval, SetTimeout). I want an infinite loop with my function call. But browser stucks when i do it

Comment: Why not?  The context would help to formulate an answer.  Otherwise, this question is too broad.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles I want to get an infinite loop with console.log('something'); but browser must respond to user. That's all. Thanks. Is there any way to do this without setTimeout?

Comment: can you use ajax in your script? you need to find something that takes a moment and uses a callback, then your infinite loop won't freeze the UI. you might be able to use FileReader()'s onload if ajax is also forbidden. there's also requestAnimationFrame... and you could use a dataURL-based script tag, that should give an execution window between iterations.

Comment: I'm dying to know: why can't you use `setInterval`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can do this with setImmediate.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/setImmediate

setImmediate implementation via window.postMessage or process.nextTick or MessageChannel or script.onreadystatechange

https://github.com/YuzuJS/setImmediate/blob/master/setImmediate.js

Comment: This function is not available natively in Chrome, Firefox, Safari or Oprah. In fact it is only supported buy IE 10.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [**Web Worker**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/basic_usage).

```js
window.onload = function () {
    document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', function () {
        alert('not blocking the UI');
    });
};

(function () {
    var code = document.querySelector('script[type="text/ww"]').textContent,
        blob = new Blob([code], {type: 'text/javascript'}),
        worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));

    worker.postMessage('foo');
}());
```

```html
<script type="text/ww">
    function doWork() {
        var i = 20000;
        while (i-- > 0) {
            foo();
        }
    }

    function foo() {
        console.log('do the foo');
    }

    self.addEventListener('message', doWork, false);
</script>
<button id="button">Click Me and View the Console</button>
```